# what's the purpose of newly added api `tf.contrib.data`

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets

Before this api, I always prepare dataset in several steps following the official tutorial:
1.write samples to tfrecord file
2.read it out with a reader as string
3.decode the string to tensors
4.batch

So what's the purpose of introducing this new api? what's the difference between it and queue-based input pipeline? which one should I choose? I am also a pytorch user, pytorch has a `dataset` api, is it a "copy" from pytorch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a newer approach designed to address some of the shortcomings of queue based approach. You can see the motivating discussion [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7951)

Developer's guide for using Dataset API is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/0dfb1825ea20e7d4da6c57e4ba3710547562d423/tensorflow/docs_src/programmers_guide/datasets.md)